# Define custom test configurations in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to define a custom test configuration in sbt which runs test, but with some extra settings. I've been looking around trying to figure out how to do this, but I can't seem to get it right.

What I would like to do is something like this: `> test` which would run the normal test task and `> pipelinetest` which would exactly the same as test, only with `(javaOptions += "-Dpipeline.run=run"`.

I've figured out how the set the javaOptions for test, like this:
`javaOptions in test += "-Dpipeline.run=run"` so what I would like to be able to do is this: `javaOptions in pipelinetest += "-Dpipeline.run=run"`

How would I define `pipelinetest` to achieve this goal? Do this need to be a new task? Or does would this be a setting in `test`. I'm very new to sbt and quite confused over this at the moment, and reading the documentation didn't help, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html, in particular the sections on additional test configurations and shared sources.

Answer (score 2):

I have only a partial answer, but I thought this might be useful info.  I was just trying to do something similar for the sbt build in Spark -- I wanted to have a way to run tests with a debugger.  Mark Harrah's comment pointed me in the right direction.  The [change I made was](https://github.com/squito/spark/commit/4cf01b3e66acfd9c489718d24432b90a4bfb4f0f):

```
lazy val TestDebug = config("testDebug") extend(Test)
...
baseProject
  .configs(TestDebug)
  .settings(inConfig(TestDebug)(Defaults.testTasks): _*)
  .settings(Seq(
    javaOptions in TestDebug ++= "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
    .split(" ").toSeq))
```

This left my usual invocations of `test`, `testOnly`, etc. alone, but now I could also run `testDebug:testOnly ...`, which would use the extra options defined above.  (it probably also created `testDebug:test`, etc. with those extra options, which aren't useful, but oh well.)

I didn't really understand why, but one important part for me to get this to work was to use `inConfig(TestDebug)(Defaults.testTasks)`, instead of `inConfig(TestDebug)(Defaults.testSettings)`.

In my case, I ran into trouble figuring out how to (a) get it to work for a multi-project build and (b) our build is even weirder b/c its based on a POM file, which makes the project definitions different than every example.

As usual, my issue with sbt is that I find info which seems related, but my build has some unusual aspects which makes me unable to completely cargo-cult the answer; and though it seems like I need trivial modifications, without a thorough understanding, its hard to modify the examples.