# How do I set Java options in SBT for the test configuration only?

Tags: sbt

I currently have a command line `sbt -Dsome.configuration.option test` doing what I want, but I would like it to apply that configuration option automatically for `sbt test` (and no other sbt phase).  If my terminology is correct, then I want to set a **Java Option** for the **Test Configuration**.  How do I do this?

Searching on these terms has led me to http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html but I have not yet been able to understand it.

This question looks similar to mine:  [Define custom test configurations in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411108/define-custom-test-configurations-in-sbt)

Comment: I have been some possible solutions that involve forking, but when I add forking to my `build.sbt` other things fail.  I don't know where to begin in solving this new problem, so I would prefer a non-forking solution, if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
testOptions in Test +=
  Tests.Setup(() => sys.props += "some.configuration.option" -> "true")
```

**Caveat:**

Because you're not forking this mutates the state of the system property in the JVM running sbt itself.

Which means that after running test the first time it that system property will also be set if you, for instance, run your main from within sbt (`run`/`runMain`).